# How to get project name using activator (or sbt)?

Tags: bash, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a Play application (2.3.4) that is getting build with `activator` like this:

```
$ activator stage
```

This will build the project and generate startup script: `target/universal/stage/bin/<project name in lowercase>`.

Now, I need to get run that startup script from another bash script on my production server.

My question is - how do I get the project name (in lowercase) from `activator` or `sbt` (since `activator` wraps `sbt`) from bash, so I could run the startup script?

Or, maybe there is a better way to figure out the name of the startup script generated by `activator stage`.

Comment: Why not just list the file names in `target/universal/stage/bin`? You will only find there `project_name` and `project_name.bat`. Either way you can use `name` in sbt/activator and then convert it to lowercase.

Comment: @Salem The script I mentioned will be reused for multiple projects and I need a generic way to find the name.

Comment: for deployment you should rather use `dist` command which creates _binary version of your application and deploy it to the server without any dependency on Play itself_ (from doc). Anyway only sensible way to get the name is searching for zip file in the `target/universal` folder unzipping it and copy name without `.zip` suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A project name is concatenation of two keys **name** and **version** separated with a dash. Whit a little bit of parsing you can get a value of any key using the SBT `show <key>` command. I'm not really familiar with writing bash scripts but I hope this hint can give you enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: That's not the solution I ended up using (I relied on finding startup `.bat` file and inferring name from it) but one can use it to find project name. Accepting the answer.